# how to convert from lower case to upper case by using pattern

Tags: linux

I have a file with contents like this:

```
 t_chaos_m_quartz_locks
 t_chaos_m_quartz_blob_triggers
 t_chaos_m_quartz_calendars
```

I would like to change `^t_chaos_m_quartz_[a-z]` to `t_chaos_m_quartz_[A-Z]`,
I have tried this:

```
awk -F "t_chaos_m_quartz" '{print $FS toupper($2)}' tmp2
```

output: (I think FS means separator t_chaos_m_quartz, but it prints the whole)

```
 t_chaos_m_quartz_locks               _LOCKS
 t_chaos_m_quartz_blob_triggers       _BLOB_TRIGGERS
 t_chaos_m_quartz_calendars           _CALENDARS
```

and also: (inspired by `tr -t [a-z][A-Z]`, until it turns everything into capital)

```
cat tmp2 | tr -t [t_chaos_m_quartza-z] [t_chaos_m_quartzA-Z]  
 T_CHAOS_M_QUARTZ_LOCKS
 T_CHAOS_M_QUARTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS
 T_CHAOS_M_QUARTZ_CALENDARS
```

the strangest is: (I cannot find a way to describe output)

```
cat tmp2 | tr -t t_chaos_m_quartz[a-z] [A-Z]
NISXQEFIHIJKQMNOIlES]F
NISXQEFIHIJKQMNOIRlERINMYWWUMF
NISXQEFIHIJKQMNOISQlUnTQMF
```

Please illustrate how to have: (and please try to explain why above has their output)

```
 t_chaos_m_quartz_LOCKS
 t_chaos_m_quartz_BLOB_TRIGGERS
 t_chaos_m_quartz_CALENDARS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the dollar sign in `FS` to make it work:

```
awk -F "t_chaos_m_quartz" '{print FS toupper($2)}' tmp2
```

**Why doesn't `$FS` work?**

When you prepend a dollar sign to `FS`, `awk` interprets it as a [positional parameter](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-14):

> A positional variable is not a special variable, but a function triggered by the dollar sign

that is, `$FS` doesn't return `FS`'s value, but is interpreted as `$0` and outputs the entire line instead.

When using variables in `awk`, refer to them simply by their names.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to convert from lower case to upper case is by using a function called toupper.

The following code will work if you are just converting a single letter:

char_to_upper = toupper(char)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).